# Why isn't my thread doing anything?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have the following code in a form called Fetch.vb:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel ' might not be needed?
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Fetch

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
End Sub

 Private Sub btnFetch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFetch.Click
    Dim ctrl As Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
            If ctrl.Text.Length = (Not 0) Then
                tbList.Add(ctrl.Text)
                MsgBox(tbList.Item(0).ToString)
                Exit For
            End If

        End If
    Next

    ' ProcessLinks()
    btnFetch.Enabled = False
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Public Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.DoWork, AddressOf backgroundWorker1_DoWork
    ProcessLinks()
End Sub

End Class
```

Now process links is a module with a public sub in with the code I am trying to run, I don't need any arguments passed to it, and it doesn't do anything that (I think) could affect this, I think I'm just doing the threading code wrong. I have backgroundworker1 in my fetch.vb form, and when I click btn Fetch, the program does nothing.

Any help and guidance or reading material would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** Here is my LinkProcess module.

```
Public Module LinkProcess

Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles Fetch.BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    ProcessLinks()
End Sub

    Public Sub ProcessLinks()
    Dim tbContent As String

        For Each tbContent In Fetch.tbList
                Process.Start(tbContent)
        Next


    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: **1.** Off-topic advice: Instead of checking whether the `BackgroundWorker.IsBusy`, simply disable the `btnFetch` button (and enable it again once the background work is completed). From a user experience standpoint, it doesn't make sense to have an enabled button that doesn't do anything. **2.** Incidentally, this might also remove a potential source of errors; namely, have you verified that `.IsBusy` is actually `False` during the first button click?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will do it like this straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your ProcessLinks() method do? Is it accessing any UI elements - like setting some text in label, or adding text a TextBox, etc.? If that is the case, then that won't work. You should not access the UI elements from inside your BackgroundWorker DoWork.

Here is a small post I wrote about how to use the BackgroundWorker correctly. This might help you.
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?680130-Correct-way-to-use-the-BackgroundWorker

Comment: It doesn't modify any UI elements, it just loops through the textboxes on a form and runs process.start on the contents. Thanks for the link though, will give it a read.

Comment: ok.. So I was correct. Don't access the TextBoxes from your BackgroundWorker DoWork. Put them in variables etc. before calling the RunWorkerAsync().

Comment: I stuck the contents into a list of string, and now the code will skip my backgroundworker1.dowork sub... I tried putting the backgroundworker1.dowork sub in the same module that contains the ProcessLinks sub. Now I have the Error "Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types"

Comment: You have somehow removed the Handles clause of the DoWork function. Put that back and it should work. `Public Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork`